# How to create a silent propeller aircraft?

Tags: engineering, flight, aircraft

Which engine type would allow a propeller aircraft to operate silently?

Comment: You might find some of [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/lessons-in-writing-questions) useful.

Comment: I have edited the question as to make it as simple as possible

Comment: Read up on the YO3-A "silent" observation aircraft used in the Viet-Nam war

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electric engines can be very quiet, but it's not the engine, it's propellers that would give away the most noise. So that would be the most challenging part. Check out [Silent Drone](http://fpvdronereviews.com/reviews/silent-drone-technology/)

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander noted in his answer, the engine itself is the smaller part of your problem. A spinning propeller or tiltrotor will be noisy.

- While they are not *exactly* a propeller aircraft, consider what is known about [stealth helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_helicopter) used by the US. In addition to radar stealth, they have sound baffling measures.
- A propeller aircraft may be designed with a good *glide ratio* and turn the engine off on the final approach. Think of something like a [motor glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_glider). This will reduce the payload and make vertical takeoff and landing impossible, of course, but the landing distance may be low. Did you ever watch the movie [Escape from New York](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082340/)?